# When I hit on Checkbox, element not interactable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, selenium-rc

When i Hit on checkbox here error display.

```
WebElement  checkbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"modelSelfRegistration\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/label"));

if(!checkbox.isSelected())

checkbox.click();
```

Screenshot for my code & error below.

http://prntscr.com/nkavtz

Comment: provide html code.. looks locator issue

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript to click on the element, rather using `checkbox.click();`

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
 js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",checkbox);
```